# Decoding array of URL objects using NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm trying to decode an array of URL objects using NSKeyedUnarchiver. Here is the code:

```
let urlArray: [URL] = [URL(string: "https://apple.com")!,
                       URL(string: "https://google.com")!]

do {
    let archivedUrls = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: urlArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    let _ = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: archivedUrls)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSURL'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray
)}'." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSURL'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray
)}'.}
```

If I replace `let _ = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: archivedUrls)` by `let _ = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSURL.self], from: archivedUrls)`, then it works. But that means it can decode either an `NSArray` or `NSURL` object, not an `NSArray` containing `NSURL` objects.

If I change the array to be an array of `String` instead, everything works fine:

```
let stringArray: [String] = ["string", "string2"]

do {
    let archivedStrings = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: stringArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    let _ = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: archivedStrings)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation for that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require Secure Coding (`requiringSecureCoding: false`), you can use `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:)`.

```
do {
    let archivedUrls = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: urlArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    if let urls = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(archivedUrls) as? [URL] {
        print(urls)
    } else {
        print("not URLs")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or you can specify the types included in the archive using `unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)`.

```
do {
    let archivedUrls = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: urlArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    if let urls = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSURL.self], from: archivedUrls) as? [URL] {
        print(urls)
    } else {
        print("not URLs")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`NSString` seems to be an exception for this rule.